# Can we save and resume winrar jobs?

Tags: windows, compression, winrar

I'm trying to zip a 87 GB folder into multiple volumes, 1 GB each.

[WinRar](http://www.rarlab.com/) is able to do that, however the entire *job* takes about 20 hours.

Is there anyway to save and resume the state of the WinRar program, such that I can accomplish the *job* in 5 sessions of 4 hour each?

Comment: 7zip allows *pausing*. I wonder if winrar might have a similar option

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - WinRAR does indeed, but doesn't let you save it to exit and enter back and resume AFAIK.

Comment: A perhaps overkill solution will be executing the job inside a VM. You can save the VM state and restart your computer and resume the VM later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I have tried, no, this is not possible.

I have tried making 5MB archives and then pausing the operation. The pausing of the operation pauses the archiving like it says, but the file being archived is still in use, so this is only useful if you need to cut down on CPU usage. It is not possible to power off the machine, remove a device with the material being archived on it, etc.

If you try to cancel an operation there is no way to resume (again, from what I have tried so far) the operation - you have to start from the beginning again, as it will try to overwrite all of the previous volumes created.

Comment: Is there a *plugin* for this feature?